# Extracting year from date time variable

Tags: r, datetime

I have some date/times in a variable where I would only like to extract the year.

Here is an example:

```
2/14/21 4:55
```

I would only like to extract '2021' from this.

By the way, the `class` for this variable is 'character'.

```
> class(df$DTS)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: You can't "extract" `2021` from your sample data, since it's not actually there.  Does every element of your data follow the format you've given?  If so, simple substrings followed by concatenation would work. otherwise, a more robust sultion would involve conversion to a `DateTime` followed by extraction of the year.  By the way, your example is ambiguous: does it use the format `d/m/y` or `m/d/y`?  It's impossible to tell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
"2/10/21 6:55" |> mdy_hm() |> year()
# [1] 2021
```

Comment: Or `... dmy_hm() ...` should OP have European dates... ;=)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution:

```
as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct("2/10/21 6:55", format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"), "%Y"))

[1] 2021
```